# How to freeze first row with one line of code

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, freeze

I create Excel files with an Access database where I also formating the excel files. I want to freeze the first row in the excel file with a more simplified code.

This works pretty well:

```
wksExcel.Range("A2").Select
wbkExcel.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

But is it possible to do it with only one row of code like this:

```
wksExcel.Range("A2").Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

Comment: Is your point just to avoid `Select`ing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with just one command, since the Range object cannot be combined with the ActiveWindow object that way. If you are after code that splits the sheet without selecting a cell, you can use something like this:

```
With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 1
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that "Range object cannot be combined with the ActiveWindow object that way".

Answer (score 0):

This generic function will freeze a worksheet pane from within Excel without a Select.

You can cut it down to your specific purpose.

```vb
' Freezes a worksheet pane top-left down to the top-left
' corner of the cell of RowIndex and ColumIndex.
'
' If RowIndex or ColumnIndex is less than 2 or omitted,
' only columns or rows respectively are frozen.
' If RowIndex and ColumnIndex are less than 2 or omitted,
' freezing of the worksheet is terminated.
'
' 2017-09-21. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Sub FreezeWorksheet( _
    ByVal Index As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal RowIndex As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnIndex As Long = 1)

    Const NoSplitIndex  As Long = 0

    Dim Freeze          As Boolean
    Dim CallIndex       As Long
    Dim ScreenUpdating  As Boolean

    ' Switching of the active window may happen, so
    ' disable screen updating while freezing is set.
    ScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    DoEvents

    ' Record the index of the currently active worksheet.
    CallIndex = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Index

    ' Activate the worksheet to freeze.
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Index).Activate

    ' Hide row and column numbers.
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    ' Hide formulabar.
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False

    ' Determine wether to freeze or to terminate freezing.
    Freeze = (RowIndex > 1 Or ColumnIndex > 1)
    If Freeze Then
        ' Remove an already set split.
        If ActiveWindow.Split = True Then
            ActiveWindow.Split = False
        End If
        ' Avoid errors.
        If RowIndex < 1 Then
            RowIndex = 1
        End If
        If ColumnIndex < 1 Then
            ColumnIndex = 1
        End If
        ' Set coordinates and apply freezing.
        ActiveWindow.SplitRow = RowIndex - 1
        ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = ColumnIndex - 1
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Else
        ' Terminate split and freeze.
        ActiveWindow.SplitRow = NoSplitIndex
        ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = NoSplitIndex
        ActiveWindow.Split = False
    End If

    ' Return to the previously active worksheet.
    DoEvents
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CallIndex).Activate
    ' Restore status of screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdating

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow it works but it is much more code as I expected ;-)

Comment: True. But that's the difference between _quick-n-dirty_ and production code. If it fits your purpose, then please mark as answered.